# msxml fails to correctly close <link> tags during XSLT transformation

Tags: .net, xslt, msxml

I'm trying to parse a RSS feed using C#, and I need to transform it with XSLT. Here's a snippet of my XSLT:

```
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="rss/channel/item" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rss/channel/item">
    <item>
    <link><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(./link)" /></link>
      </item>
</xsl:template>
```

Using a [random RSS (the *corriere della serra*)](http://www.corriere.it/rss/homepage.xml), this renders correctly with XML Spy:

```
<item>
<link>http://www.corriere.it/este(...)2aabc.shtml</link>
</item>
<item>
<link>http://www.corriere.it/cron(...)22a-11de-bb1e-00144f02aabc.shtml</link>
</item>
...
```

But when using the Microsoft .net tool (either withing my code or using the Visual Studio XSLT debugger), I get:

```
<item>
<link>http://www.corriere.it(...)11de-aaa2-00144f02aabc.shtml
    </item>
    <item>
    <link>http://corrieredelmezzogiorno.corriere.it/le(...)03131900.shtml
        </item>
    <item>
```

The `</link>` markup is not output at all. If I change "link" for "XXX", this works perfectly, but this is unfortunately not an option.

Any idea of what is happening here???

Comment: Unless you post the code that produces the malformed output, I don't think that somebody here can help you. Theoretically, the shown output is impossible to produce with XSLT alone.

Comment: That's what's weird. Using the XSLT debugger shipped with Visual Studio outside of any code, I still get that output.

Comment: Debugger bug? Strange thing. What does `XsltCompiledTransform` produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for those wondering, msxml doesn't close link tags while in `method="html"` mode. If you change the first line to

```
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

The above code works perfectly...

Comment: Right, that's it. I should have thought about this, but it didn't occur to me either.